# GTK/C sharing data and variables between functions

Tags: c, callback, gtk, global, data-sharing

The problem is: what's the best way to share data between functions, but specifically in GTK/C application? The best means the most 'proper', the fastest in run and/or absorbing as low CPU power as possible.
I'm asking because I have to code some app with GUI under linux, but I'm rather a microcontroller programmer (and maybe it's hard to me to think like big computer). In small 8-bit MCU's world, where code is in plain C, globals are the fastest and commonly used way to share data between functions.
But I guess that in much more complicated app running under operating system there must be other 'special' way to do that. To this point I noticed that GTK (GDK, Glib etc.) offer many special functions and build-in mechanisms to makes programmer's life easiest, so I suppose it should be something elegant for sharing variables between functions.
Searching through the net I've seen different solutions:
- classes with private variables and methods to get/set them - but my app is coded in C, not C++, I'd like to avoid using object programming,
- global structs or even one big global struct with many members,
- good plain globals,
- GtkClipboard, but I think it's for different purposes.

What I want to do is simply to set some variable 'A' in one callback function, set that variable once again in second callback, and then in another callback do something depending upon value of variable 'A', like this:

```
callback_func1{
//...
A = some_func();
//...
}
callback_func2{
//...
A = another_func();
//...
}
callback_func3{
//...
if(A>threshold) do_something();
else do_nothing();
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to be wary of globals, especially if you only want to allow certain functions to be modifying them.

Assuming you're retaining more data than just `A` (which for simplicity I've defined as `int`), you can set up your structure in the familiar way

```
typedef struct t_MYCBSD
{
    int A;
    // other members
} MYCBSD; // callback struct data
```

including other data members as necessary. (I've included the `t_MYCBSD` in case there is some self-referencing).

You can then implement your callback functions as follows:

```
void callback_func1( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data )
{
    MYCBSD *data = user_data;
    data->A = some_func();
}

void callback_func2( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data )
{
    MYCBSD *data = user_data;
    data->A = another_func();
}

void callback_func3( GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data )
{
    MYCBSD *data = user_data;

    if( data->A > threshold ) do_something();
    else do_nothing();
}
```

Obviously, `some_func()`, `another_func()`, `threshold`, `do_something()` and `do_nothing()` are valid in this context.

**NOTE:** the `data` pointer to your struct makes the syntax a little more clear. You can also use:

```
((MYCBSD *) user_data)->A = some_func();
```

In any case, you usually set up your callbacks when creating your widgets. In the following (heavily culled, non-GtkBuilder) code, `MYCBSD mydata` will be locally scoped. I'm assuming the callbacks will be set for some buttons with the "clicked" event.

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    MYCBSD mydata;
    // Below-referenced widgets
    GtkWidget *mywidget1, *mywidget2, *mywidget3;
    // ... other widgets and variables

    mydata.A = 0;   // Optionally set an initial value to A

    // Standard init via gtk_init( &argc, &argv );

    // ... Create the toplevel and a container of some kind

    // Create mywidget1,2,3 (as buttons, for example)
    mywidget1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("widget1");
    mywidget2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("widget2");
    mywidget1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("widget3");

    g_signal_connect( mywidget1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback_func1), &mydata );
    g_signal_connect( mywidget2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback_func2), &mydata );
    g_signal_connect( mywidget3, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback_func3), &mydata );

    // ... Attach those widgets to container
    // ... and show all

    // Run the app in a standard way via gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

The important lines here are:

```
    g_signal_connect( mywidget1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback_func1), &mydata );
    g_signal_connect( mywidget2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback_func2), &mydata );
    g_signal_connect( mywidget3, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(callback_func3), &mydata );
```

where the last parameter passes your data to the callback functions.

If you're only looking to share a single value, `A`, you can pass that in a similar way without the need of a struct.

Comment: Heh, I've been using structures like these ones to share Gtk Widgets between callbacks and I didn't think it is also the simplest way to share flags and variables. Now it's clear!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use globals, just use globals. And, regardless of what the world says, nobody died because used globals.

Globals are avoided because make maintenance hard on **big** programs and, from your description, this just does not seem to be the case.

On the sharing side, GTK+ programs are usually not parallel, so you can freely access globals in RW without problems. And also when tasks are used, it is best practice to put all the GTK+ calls on the same task: you are still allowed to access globals in RW from the same task.

Comment: My program grows up and, as You said, slowly becomes "big and hard to maintain". Packing globals into structures is also a question of "good programming practice", even in small and simply apps, don't You think?

Comment: Packing data into a struct and instantiate it in the global space *means* using globals. You specifically asked for the fastest way of sharing data in GTK+ and the answer is using globals. It brings in some disadvantages, but they are mostly organisational, not technical.

Comment: Interesting, what disadvantages did You mean?

Comment: It makes maintenance hard on big programs, e.g. you should carefully choose variable names to avoid clashes. In small/medium projects this is a non-issue.